# How does this code count all subsets of a set of positive integers whose sum is even?

Tags: algorithm, sum, subset

I came across this piece of code in a TopCoder solution that puzzles me. There is an array list of positive even and odd integers. I think it returns the number of subsets whose sum is even modulus MOD. I believe the MOD is there just to avoid overflow if the list is large so if you keep the number less than 32 then I don't think you need it.

```
ArrayList l = { ... positive even and odd integers ... };

int dp[] = {1,0};
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i) {
        int even = dp[0];
        int odd = dp[1];
        if (l.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
                even *= 2;
                odd *= 2;
        } else {
                even += odd;
                odd = even;
        }
        dp[0] = even % MOD;
        dp[1] = odd % MOD;
}
return (dp[0] - 1 + MOD) % MOD;
```

If all integers are even, then I think the answer is 2^N-1.
But it seems if there is at least one odd integer, the answer becomes 2^(N-1)-1. Is that right? If so, why keep track of even / odd counts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not need an iterative program at all.  Suppose your set has N elements, k even, and N-k odd. Then, the k even numbers are not really relevant; any of the 2^k combinations of them, together with the subsets of the odd numbers with even sums, combines to an even sum.

How many combinations of the odd numbers have even sum? If N-k > 0, there are 2^(N - k - 1) of them.  So, you are right.  This is a coding problem and not a math problem.

But the given algorithm is as follows:

When N = 0, there is only one subset of the set: the empty set, which sums to 0.  So, start with `even=1` and `odd=0`. Now the inductive step: suppose the numbers of partitions for the first k elements are `even` and `odd`.

If the k+1-th number is even, than any subset of the first k whose sum is even can have the k+1-th element appended (or not), doubling the number of even subsets.  The same applies for the subsets with odd sums.

If the k+1-th number is odd, then any subset of the first k numbers whose sum is even does not give any new even subsets with the k+1-th number, while the a subset of the first k numbers whose sum is odd gives one with an even sum if the k+1-th is appended.  So, the new `even` is the sum of the old `even` and `odd`.  Similarly, the new `odd` is also the same sum, so the new `odd` equals the new `even`.

Note that `even + odd == 2^k` for all k, no matter what.  And, once there is an odd number, `even == odd` for that index and all higher.